# How to change value of Text widget in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to change the value of `Text` widget in Flutter when a function triggers

```
Text('Initial Text')
```

---

```
void UpdateText(){
   //Here i want the code to update the value of text widget
}
```

Comment: Editor's note: please don't clutter posts with content not related to the problem at hand. The comment section is specifically for addressing others. Also, be advised that the only reason to not close a post is for it to be on-topic - no amount of pleading will help otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this

```
// Declare this variable 
String myText = "Initial Text";

Text(myText),

void UpdateText(){
  setState(() {
    myText = "Another text";
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, define a value outside of methods.

```
String textValue="Example value";
```

Then, set this value in your text widget.

```
Text(textValue);
```

But remember, if the app image needs to be updated you need to use StatefulWidget. Don't use StatelessWidget.

And now create the update method with setstate. The setstate method allows you to update the view and rebuild.
like this;

```
 void UpdateText(){
     setState((){
        textValue = "New value";
     });
 }
```

Comment: but if i navigate to other screen, and come back to same screen where i update the text widget text it display the old value

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `setState` method to update the value of your variable

e.g.

```
var a="hello";

return Text(a);
```

and the method should look like this

```
void UpdateText(){
   setState((){
     a="world";
   });
}
```

Make sure your widget is stateful widget

Answer (score 0):

Use 'provider' state management to update the text when needed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35655256)